# Get the initial scrollwidth of ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an table and a search input which is searching data inside table.
I should have the tables data scrollWidth for creating tooltip (if the text is bigger than the space).
The ref.current.scrollWidth at first gives me the correct scrollWidth but after typing smth in input the scrollWidth is changing. The problem is that I need the initial ref scrollWidth when searching. How to save the first getting scrollWidth and do not allow update the value.

I tried to save some state and update only on useEffect but thats not helping

I'm using ref.current.scrollWidth

I tried to save the data inside useState like

```
    const [descRef, setDestref] = useState<number | undefined>();
```

And using useEffect to add the data to descRef

```
   useEffect(() => {
    setDestref(elementRef.current?.scrollWidth);
   }, []);
```

Comment: If you just need to save a numerical value and not the entire element, just use `useMemo` or `useRef`

Comment: I'm not saving the entire element just value, with useRef I'm getting the scrollwith this will not help here I think